# What is the use of requestflow.cs in paypal sample

Tags: c#, paypal

I have to integrate PayPal in one of my projects. Can someone explain to me the use of `Requestflow` class they have used?

1. Why do we need to track the request flow?
2. What is the need of adding guid and session?